# sas graphical symbol in proc report not displaying correctly

Tags: html, sas

I use to emulate a bar chart in proc report by using

```
compute ChartBar / char length=195; 
   ChartBar=repeat('&#9608;',int(N*29/&Nmax));
 endcomp;
```

The problem is that now I get the character '&' followed by amp;#9608; in the HTML resulting file instead of "█"

An example for testing:

```
ods html file="eee .html"  path="C:\temp"  nogtitle style=styles.sasweb;
data;
  x=repeat( '&#9608;',10);
proc print;
run;
ods html close;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try just using a hex literal instead?  `'9608'x`

Comment: Post a short working program so others can test. Use either a SASHELP dataset, like CLASS or CARS, or post a simple data step to create the test data.

Comment: It may have something to do with the SAS9.4 as I didn't have the issue with previous versions?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use HTML code, just use the character that you want. Make sure you are using a font that has a glyph for that character.

```
data test;
  x=repeat( '9608'x,10);
run;
proc print;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

HTML entity `&#9608;` (symbol name Full Block) is rendered by browsers as character █.

The ODS HTML destination default is to protect a cell's value rendering, which will thus prevent HTML injection.  A style override can turn off the protecting behavior and alter other defaults of the destinaton.

```
ods html file="eee .html"  path="C:\temp"  nogtitle style=styles.sasweb;

data;
  * variable x containing value that needs to be HTML rendered;
  x=repeat( '&#9608;',10);  

proc print;
  var x / style(data)=[ProtectSpecialChars=OFF];
run;

ods html close;
```